# Dynamically changing text box size depending upon device

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve setting the text box size according to the device used to view my web page.  My web page renders ok across all platforms satisfactorily apart the text box is too wide on mobile devices.

I've researched this forum and have found snippets of code that have helped me work up a solution that works but it is not ideal but shows me I'm on the right path.  Currently I'm using function 'onkeyup' but I'd much rather have a type of 'onload' function but I know from studying this forum that this is not possible.  I've tried using 'document.getElementById' but can't see how I can use this to change attribute 'size'.  Grateful for any suggestions - this is my code as it stands:

Function:

```
function resize(obj){

var textboxlength;

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

textboxlength=20;
}
else
{
textboxlength=60;
};
obj.size=textboxlength;
console.log(textboxlength);
}
```

And this is the Input entity:

```
<input type="TEXT" autocomplete="off" name="message" id="AJH1" size="10" onkeyup="resize(this)">

<input type="SUBMIT" value="Ask">
```

This works but is not elegant - much rather find something to replace 'onkeyup'.  Thanks.

Comment: I may be wrong ... but are you trying to implement the responsive web design with the JS?

Comment: it seems that way to me too. you should try using CSS media queries instead -> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: you may want to use vm measures : http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier and proper to use CSS to handle responsive design for you.
You can acheive it by defining device's screen resolution queries.
Full example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    @media (max-width: 900px) {
        #AJH1 {
            width:20px;
        }
      }
      
    @media (min-width: 901px) {
        #AJH1 {
            width:60px;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="TEXT" autocomplete="off" name="message" id="AJH1">
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="Ask">
</body>
```

More examples and samples you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en)

If u want to test it IE11 have some nice dev tools for it. Open file with this code press F12 and then go to last tab called "Emulation". Under "Display" section you can choose lower resolution and the size of input will change.

Comment: Thanks @Glapa - This looks like what I'm looking for - I just tried this by wrapping the suggested css in 'style' tags within the head of my page, removed the resize and onkeyup functions but it didn't seem to work - did I miss something?

Comment: Thanks again @Glapa.  I've put the code up at [link](http://www.nicobloc.com/temp/testdevice.html) - can't seem to get it working though - tested on Firefox, Windows 8 and Android mobile phone.

Comment: Can i ask what is the resolution of your mobile device with android?

Comment: Yes, I tested on 5 devices - PC Win XP 1024x768, PC Win 7 1920x1080, PC Win 8 1920x1080, Samsung Galaxy Tab2 Android 1280x800 and Samsung Galaxy Ace phone 320x480.  Tried web page at [link](http://www.nicobloc.com/temp/testdevice.html) on all 5 devices and didn't see the text field size change on any.  Maybe I didn't copy the code correctly to the webpage (nicobloc.com/temp/testdevice.html) but I think I did.

Comment: I think I owe you apology @Glapa - just realised that you took my input text box sizes of 20 and 60 (which presumably are no. of characters) and you used same numbers but for px which is why it didn't appear much different on the various devices.  Changing my code now to use bigger px sizes to match roughly the original character sizes.

Comment: Happy to report all works fine - slaps head for making fundamental measurement error.

Comment: Well it's one of the drawbacks of this method. Mobile devices became to handle higher and higher resolutions despite of screen size.